# github page: image does not load properly

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages

This is my github repository: https://github.com/lisiyitoy/run_sonic

I am making a Javascript game: when you type the correct letter, the Sonic on the bottom will run forward. The page runs properly when I open it locally in my computer. However, Sonic flashes when I open the github page link: https://lisiyitoy.github.io/run_sonic/ It seems some of the PNG images do not show properly. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: The missing images (./images/NN.PNG) are accessible, and referenced by the source. Perhaps you should prefetch them, eg. by including them in a hidden div?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Sonic flashes". Seems to work ok for me.

Comment: @ConradParker how to prefetch them?

Comment: @eis when you type the letters, the sonic will flash. This means some image cannot be shown or loaded on the page. However if you clone the repository and run HTML page locally, everything work fine

Comment: @siyili There's many ways, in HTML, CSS or Javascript; search for "prefetch images" and choose your favourite way :)

Comment: Your first link is a 404.